# Is there a way to use map function or for loop for melting? I need to melt 5 dataframes with same line of code

Tags: python, pandas

I have 6 dataframes with me called
`open_price`, `closed_price`, `volume`, `adj_open_price`, `high_price` and `low_price`

And each dataframe has values like this

[This is before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5wmX.png)

[This is my goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBXR7.png)

I know how to do it manually (without for loop or map)
just apply `pd.melt` to each Dataframe and keep merging the results:

```
open=pd.melt(open_price,
             value_vars=['GOOG','AMZN','APPL','FB','NFLX','SBUX','TSLA'],
             var_name='Firm', 
             value_name='Open',
             id_vars=['Firm'])

close=pd.melt(close_price,
              value_vars=['GOOG','AMZN','APPL','FB','NFLX','SBUX','TSLA'],
              var_name='Firm', 
              value_name='Close',
              id_vars=['Firm'])

openclose = pd.merge(open,close)
```

and so on.

Is there a way to make this repetitive tasks into one?

I need to change the `value_name` to its respective dataframe’s name as well.

Thank you!!

Comment: Hello and welcome to stack overflow. Could you edit your question and provide examples of your input dataframes you are trying to put together, and an example of your output dataframe from the same data? This will help understand what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Hi! done! let me know if you need more info

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

Put dataframes in a list then apply pd.melt with map.

```
dfs = [df1, df2]

result=list(map(lambda df:pd.melt(...), dfs))

df_1, df_2 = result
```

So in your case this would be:

```
dataframess = [open_price, low_price]


openn=pd.melt(df, value_vars=['GOOG','AMZN','APPL','FB','NFLX','SBUX','TSLA'],\
             var_name='Firm', value_name='Open',id_vars=['Firm'])

low=pd.melt(low_price, id_vars=['Date'], value_vars=['GOOG','AMZN','APPL','FB','NFLX','SBUX','TSLA'],\
             var_name='Firm', value_name='Low')

result=list(map(lambda x: pd.melt(low_price, id_vars=['Date'], value_vars=['GOOG','AMZN','APPL','FB','NFLX','SBUX','TSLA'],\
             var_name='Firm', value_name='x'),dataframess))
```

The last line you dont neccessarily need to pass map into list.
Because map returns a generator through which you can loop.

Comment: I still get an error. let me rephrase my question. thank you !!